# Send recurring reminders to Google Form respondents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to create a Google form like below :

[image]

My objective is to send an reminder of Activity Described in < Your Activity > Question

Then I need to send reminder email to email mentioned in < Email > Question, With Selected Frequency in < Frequency > Question i.e. recurring reminders !

I searched for examples and add-ons but haven't got anything. I think I can program it with someone's kind guidance.

Comment: See [Sending Confirmation Emails from Google Apps Forms](http://securitasdato.blogspot.com/2014/11/sending-confirmation-emails-from-google.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a lot of things with Google Forms responses with basic programming skills and knowing JavaScript as ome tasks with Google Forms responses could be automated with [Google Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/) with a bounded script to the form.

One of the keys for your project is to use Google Apps Script [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), specifically [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to be able to do automate recurring tasks like sending recurring reminders.

## References

- [Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Google Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)
- [Sending Confirmation Emails from Google Apps Forms](http://securitasdato.blogspot.com/2014/11/sending-confirmation-emails-from-google.html)

Comment: Thank you Ruben, your references helped. BTW this also helped me a lot.....if anyone just begins with Google Forms, then have a reference from here as well .....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9Ej6PCeO6s